# How to replace iframe in IE9

Tags: javascript

Is there a way with javascript to replace an iframe, for example

```
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
```

with a link like this...

```
<a href="">go here</a>
```

only if browser detects IE9? If I write a pure javascript code from my `<head></head>` area.  I want this action to occur before the iframe is fully loaded onto the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to target IE 9 and write a script to change out the `iframe`. Or you can try to use the conditional comment to select which tag gets displayed directly.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<a href="">go here</a>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: thats half the solution for me.  thank YOU Austin. I figured out how to remove the element, but how do I replace it with an anchor link with pure javascript?l

Comment: can i put that IE9 tag inside the body? or does it only work in the head?

Comment: In the article I link to they use an example if it in the body. I'll update my answer with something for you to try